# pointer assignment

Tags: c++

I have the following template structure:

```
template <typename scalar_type>
struct postc_params{
    scalar_type delta; 
    unsigned int time_horizon; 
    matrix_math::matrix<scalar_type> dynamics;
    boost::shared_ptr<continuous_set> invariant_set_ptr;
    boost::shared_ptr<continuous_set> input_set_ptr;
    boost::shared_ptr<continuous_set> initial_set_ptr;
};
```

Now, I have a templated class with a private member of the above structure type

```
template <typename scalar_type>
class A{
....
private:
....
postc_params<scalar_type> my_postc;
};
```

Inside a member function definition of class A, I have the following line of code:

```
my_postc.initial_set_ptr = my_postc.initial_set_ptr->transform(some_obj);
```

transform function returns a pointer of type

```
boost::shared_ptr<continuous_set>
```

With this code, I have the following error:

passing 'const boost::shared_ptr' as 'this' argument of 'boost::shared_ptr<  >& boost::shared_ptr<  >::operator=
 (const boost::shared_ptr&) [with Y = const continuous::continuous_set, T = continuous::continuous_set]' discards qualifiers

Can anyone help me out with the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the member function in A `const`?

If I am reading your code right, you are trying to change a member of a class from a const member function which is not allowed. Either remove the `const` from the member function or make the member `mutable`.

So,

```
mutable postc_params<scalar_type> my_postc;
```

However, I would take care with this method. Maybe reevaluate why the method that is changing `my_postc` is `const`. Either it should not be `const` or it should not be changing `my_postc`.

Comment: To throw in my 2 cents, this is not what I would consider a "good" place to use `mutable`.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to assign to a `const` pointer as per the error message: "passing 'const boost::shared_ptr' as 'this' argument"

the member function you mention is surely `const` hence the error

you should rather reconsider your design than throw `mutable` here and there in your code.